# Make Xcode warn when image literals don't point to images

Tags: xcode, image-literals

Is it possible to have a warning if image literals are used but the associated images no longer exist?

i.e. if the image has been removed or renamed etc...

Comment: That's a good question... One possible solution would be a script in the build phase that matches `#imageLiteral` calls against the contents of the assets folder, but I would love to know as well if a proper solution exists (like a flag in the build settings for example)...

Comment: @Alladinian I had a look through the build settings and tried a few of them that looked like they might work but nothing seemed to do it.